# Invalid cmp type when trying to test tcf consents

Tags: javascript, amp-html, cmp

I'm trying to implement TCF 2.0 consents on amp page.

Here is a sample code which I took from https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/blob/master/examples/amp-consent/cmp-vendors.amp.html

```
 <!-- _ping_ example -->
  <amp-consent id='ABC' layout='nodisplay' type='_ping_'>
    <script type="application/json">
      {
        "consents": {},
        "postPromptUI": "postPromptUI",
        "clientConfig": {
          "CMP_id": "test_id",
          "other_info": "test_info"
        }
      }
    </script>
    <div id="postPromptUI">
      Post Prompt UI
      <button on="tap:ABC.prompt(consent=_ping_)" role="button">Manage</button>
    </div>
  </amp-consent>
  <!-- End _ping_ example -->
```

Instead, in console I get an error: amp-consent/consent-config : invalid CMP type *ping*.

Does someone faced with such problem ? Have no idea where to find a solution :(